# allow only numbers, TAB , DELETE, BACKSPACE, Left Arrow, Right Arrow in angular material 2 input field

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-material2

I'm trying to block chars and other keyboard inputs, except **Numbers**,**Tab Key**, **Backspace**, **Delete**, **Left Arrow**, **Right Arrow**

I just tried following code, but this can type few characters,

```
<input type="text" matInput required name="mobileNumber"  onkeypress='return ((event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57) || (event.charCode >= 96 && event.charCode <= 105) || (event.keyCode == 8 || event.keyCode == 9 || event.keyCode == 46 || event.keyCode == 37 || event.keyCode == 39))'>
```

this is [the working example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpeqpc?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.html)

How can I block those properly

Comment: Uh, how about `<input type="number"/>`? Blocking by keycode input is really not idiomatic web development, and sounds [very XY](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Comment: Your working example doesn't work to me

Comment: @verxy then um getting up and down arrows at the end of input fields, I want to stop that too

Comment: @Haitam okay try nw, e and few chars can type there

Answer (score 0):

Below is my solution:

```
import { Directive, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
    selector: '[myNumberOnly]'
})
export class NumberOnlyDirective {
    // Allow decimal numbers. The \. is only allowed once to occur
    private regex: RegExp = new RegExp(/^[0-9]+(\.[0-9]*){0,1}$/g);

    // Allow key codes for special events. Reflect :
    // Backspace, tab, end, home
    private specialKeys: Array<string> = [ 'Backspace', 'Tab', 'End', 'Home' ];

    constructor(private el: ElementRef) {
    }

    @HostListener('keydown', [ '$event' ])
    onKeyDown(event: KeyboardEvent) {
        // Allow Backspace, tab, end, and home keys
        if (this.specialKeys.indexOf(event.key) !== -1) {
            return;
        }

        // Do not use event.keycode this is deprecated.
        // See: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/KeyboardEvent/keyCode
        let current: string = this.el.nativeElement.value;
        // We need this because the current value on the DOM element
        // is not yet updated with the value from this event
        let next: string = current.concat(event.key);
        if (next && !String(next).match(this.regex)) {
            event.preventDefault();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried your approach like this https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpeqpc-s1yb6n?file=app%2Finput-overview-example.ts seems not working

Comment: this work but no decimals https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gpeqpc-4oqxyz?file=app/input-overview-example.ts

Answer (score 0):

I'm pretty sure you're wondering what's the issue here, since the char codes you're using are HTML Char Codes and you are definetly using the right ones. The problem here is that your `onkeypress` event gives you the ASCII code of the characters, that's why you can type from `'a'` to `'i'` in your input field.

What I will suggest is to just leave it like this

```
onkeypress='return (event.charCode >= 48 && event.charCode <= 57)'
```

The other keys (arrows, delete, etc..) will still work.

Comment: but your solution "Delete" , "Tab" and other keys not working in firefox